# R raster timeseries decomposition error

Tags: r, time-series, r-raster, decomposition

I am trying to decompose a monthly timeseries stack (dimensions  : 336, 221, 74256, 420) to get the random component. I am using the following:

```
tsfun <- function(x) {  
  my.ts = na.remove(ts(x, start=c(1982,1), frequency=12)) 
  my.decomp = decompose(my.ts, type="multi") 
  my.exp = my.decomp$random 
}
random <- calc(ras_in, fun=tsfun)
```

but I get the following error

Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function

Any suggestion? 
Thanks a million

Comment: It would be easier with a snippet of data containing at least 2-3 NA values. So we can test our theories before posting. It does not need to be all, just `dput(x)` the whole thing and extract a chunk, but make sure the chunk fails too, prior to posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your function is not valid. When I test it, I get:

```
tsfun(1:24)
#Error in na.remove(ts(x, start = c(1982, 1), frequency = 12)) : 
#  could not find function "na.remove"
```

Here is a version that works for me:

```
tsfun2 <- function(x) {  
  my.ts = na.omit(ts(x, start=c(1982,1), frequency=12)) 
  decompose(my.ts, type="multi")$random 
}

tsfun2(1:24)
#     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#1982  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   1   1   1   1   1   1
#1983   1   1   1   1   1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```